# ttk.button.cget usage - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I make a training application using tk, using OOP approach.
Program structure is:

```
class Calculator:
    #constants and needed variables

    def __init__(self):
        #main window stuff
        self.createWidgets()

    def setVal(self): #function
    ...
    #other functions
    ...

    def createWidgets(self): #function creating all widgets

#mainloop
```

I figured out a cool way of generating all my buttons quickly in `createWidgets` function like this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
        if i in [1,2,3]:
            ttk.Button(self.buttonLF, text=str(i), style="my.TButton", command=self.setVal).grid(row=0, column=i - 1)
        elif i in [4,5,6]:
            ttk.Button(self.buttonLF, text=str(i), style="my.TButton", command=self.setVal).grid(row=1, column=i - 4)
        else:
            ttk.Button(self.buttonLF, text=str(i), style="my.TButton", command=self.setVal).grid(row=2, column=i - 7)
```

The command function `self.setVal` goes as follows: (the `self.entry` is a simple entry field from where i get number values from)

```
def setVal(self):
    if len(self.entry.get()) >= 20:
        self.entry.delete(0, 20)
        self.entry.insert(0, "Max_length_exceeded!")
    else:
        if self.entry.get() == '':
            Calculator.old = 0
        else:
            Calculator.old = int(self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, 20)
        Calculator.new = 10 * Calculator.old

        #The part which I have problem with:
        self.entry.insert(0, str(Calculator.new + int(self.cget('text'))))
        Calculator.old = Calculator.new + int(self.cget('text'))
```

The way of me doing transfromations to show numbers in the `entry` properly is not important (the `Calculator.old` variable, etc.).
The main thing I want to do, I want to use the `ttk.button` method `cget('text')`, convert it to int and use this to calculate output showing in `self.entry` field. At the moment this code doesn't work (because of `self.cget`).
How can I properly call the `cget` to gather text from buttons created in `createWidgets` function?
Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the self statement. Inside a class, e.g. Calculator self always points to this class so here Calculator. Therefore self.cget is not pointing to the cget method in ttk.Button but looking for one in Calculator, which does not exist. Additionally you should not use Calculator inside the Calculator class but instead use self.

Now you could rewrite the setVal function to include the cget function of the respective button but that is a little cumbersome. I would instead change the setVal function to have an explicit input value. This is also more logical and can be reused more easily.

```
def setVal(self,value):
    if len(self.entry.get()) >= 20:
        self.entry.delete(0, 20)
        self.entry.insert(0, "Max_length_exceeded!")
    else:
        if self.entry.get() == '':
            self.old = 0
        else:
            self.old = int(self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, 20)
        self.new = 10 * self.old

        self.entry.insert(0, str(self.new + value))
        self.old = self.new + value)
```

When you define the buttons you can simply use the setVal function with the correct input value, which is i in your case, e.g.:

```
ttk.Button(self.buttonLF, text=str(i), style="my.TButton", command=lambda:self.setVal(i)).grid(row=0, column=i - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted.